# Neurotic frogs ought to relax in mud baths

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cipher, steganography

What is the hidden message in this advertisement?

> #### Neurotic Frogs *O*ught To Rel*a*x In *M*ud Baths!
>
> Perpendicular l*ou*nging calms. *A* frog, a m*u*d cap... bliss! Wallowing g*e*n*e*rates happiness. Amphibian sp*a* isn't expensive--seventy d*o*llars--cheap! That'*s* not *a* large e*x*pens*e* from an*y* discerning fr*o*g's money, unlik*e* Super 8.
>
> Ever*y*one--frogs, toad*s*, newts, *a*nd salamanders! G*e*t a wonderful shiat*s*u, or recei*v*e an other kind. Masseus*es* are her*e* today! Invite a fianc*é*e, supervisor, roommate, niece: *all* welcomed!
>
> Y*o*u simply ne*v*er believed these p*o*ssibilitie*s*; they're (I *swear*) absolute truth! Th*e* Montgomery A*m*phibian Salon! Come luxuriate today!

Hint 1:

> Notice that the last word in a sentence never contains italics.

Hint 2:

> Frogs, toads, or newts--makes no difference. But dogs or horses are a different story.

Hint 3:

> "Tadp*o*les" must be accompanied at all times. Our company policy states: "Business standards all*o*w only *adult* amphibians."

Hint 4:

> Eggs and tadpoles are quite different, of course. However, we don't discriminate among *e*ggs, t*ad*poles, or even *tadpoles*. On the other hand, there's a big difference between tad*p*oles and polli*wo*gs.

Comment: Italics are: OaMouAueeaosaxeyoeysaesveseéallovosswearem

Comment: Which I believe is welsh for "Get your stinking frog out of my bathtub!"

Comment: Totally off topic: This sounds like it could have been taken out of "Stand on Sansibar" (John Brunner scifi book).

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the gaps between the itallics as well?

Comment: micsthepick, the big run of 0s or 1s from the italicized "swear" near the end seem like a problem for that idea.

Comment: Honestly, the italics look like they could be a computer program from [PPCG](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/). Considering @DLosc's origins, it might not be *too* much of a stretch... though it's more likely to be something else. :D

Comment: Maybe it's time for a hint? This puzzle is driving me crazy. ;)

Comment: These italics almost look like source code for the esoteric programming language "evil". If someone has a compiler for that, please test this. I couldn't find one and I can't be bothered to write one right now.

Comment: evil didn't seem to do match with it (assuming the interpreter I just wrote based on wikipedia is correct) - it just generated the letter "o".  Running it through Pip (created by DLosc) gives 1000 (simply from the last "m" in the string).

Comment: @micsthepick You might be right, it looks like the number of normal letters (in between the italic letters) is always less than 26... (I haven't checked them all).

Comment: Iff you ignore the words "all" and "swear", which are all italicized, and I think might be a red herring, there are only nine different letters italicized (disregarding accents):  **a e m o s u v x y**

Comment: Any further progress on this one? I still can't make it out

Comment: It looks like the length of each words plays some kind of role, doesn't it? It seemed to me from the beginning like the message was written to match a certain number of letters per word, and the newest hint appears to confirm that.

Comment: If you count the number of letters in `Come luxuriate today`, it gives you `4 9 5`, and if you convert this back in letters, it gives you `DIE`. Which is what I am going to do after spending nights on this puzzle :)

Comment: Can we have another hint or it would be too much :] ? I mean, this puzzle has not been solved for 4 months...

Comment: My bounty went unspent.  :(  Maybe some collaboration?  I opened a [chat room for this puzzle](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44455/neurotic-frogs).  All welcomed!  I *really* want to see this guy solved.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The main idea:

> Convert each word: If not italicized, to word length, if italicized, then irrespective of number of italics, either to 1, if the length is odd, or 2, if length is even. Then pair each italicized to the right side word, and read in A1Z26.

The entire message reads:

> Hello, my name is Inigo Montoya. You killed my father. Prepare to die.

The #3 hint reads:

> Hint

Puzzle i*s* a, ... *I* can't. *I* puzzlingly ... *I* didn't. Don't ... *I* swear.

Thanks to @Verence and @Wu33o for having time do decrypt the message. It took me around 13+ hours to solve, ended up waking up all night, and the fourth hint reduced too many possibilities.

Comment: The message is actually a meme:
http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/you-killed-my-father-prepare-to-die

Comment: Actually, @Wu33o decrypted the message first and edited your post. But I also decrypted it and was ready to post it as a comment :-)

Comment: Good job on finding the decryption method, and I'm happy to help. Btw, the company policy in hint 3 translates to "Hint"

Comment: @Wu33o: I was way too lazy to decrypt it, thank's for decrypting both.

Comment: Congratulations for having solved this one :).

Comment: And in the end, I was right for the last word! Damn!

Comment: Rejoice, *a*ll frogs an*d* toads also! Montgomery Sal*o*n opens up! Ha*pp*y throng fill*s* street ecstatically!

Answer (score 9):

As @GentlePurpleRain noted, the only letters that are italicized are "aemosuvxy".

Now, to put that aside for a moment, consider:

During reproduction, many amphibians keep their eggs in mud structures that could resemble 'animal spas'

Also, we see that dogs and horses aren't allowed, and this nods to the fact that inter-species reproduction is impossible.

Finally, we note that this may be a sort of "adult" topic, as noted by the 3rd hint.

Taking this together with @GentlePurpleRain's observation, we realize the message is an anagram of those letters:

> A Sexy Ovum !!!!!!!!

Comment: This answer is dead wrong, but hilarious.  ;)