# Jim: You could have given me a song

Tags: cipher, story

Y'know, I thought I'd lulled **Jim** over with my [previous challenge.](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/33785/word-of-advice-if-someone-beats-you-in-a-guess-the-song-challenge-dominate-the) Turns out, Jim isn't so easy to lull over.

---

I woke up, got rid of the gunk in my eyes, and checked the time.

> 5:55 AM

Hmm, that's strange. I'm certain it's 8:30.

Ignoring the probably Jimmed clock, I went to my room, and turned on my laptop.

What awoke me was not the GRUB screen I'd known.

> ### G+0 R+8 U-12 B+14 version 5.55
>
> Ubuntu 15.10 (on /dev/sda5)
>   Ubuntu 16.04.1 (on /dev/sda12)
>   Operating System? (on /dev/sda/jim)

Jim, if you're reading this:

- a: learn Linux file conventions
- b: make your things less obvious

---

So, I opened up that GRUB entry, and was greeted with this:

> I've been obsessed with **something** lately. Can you figure out what it is?
>   Clue 1: HEADER-1T <5+1>
>   **Clue 2:**
>
> 333333333333333133333336333333363333333333333338333333363333
>   333233333333333333303333333333333338333333333333333033333333
>   0a3333333033333336333333353333333633333334333333333333333133
>   333336333333313333333633333331333333363333333133333333333333
>   350a30613333333333333337333333333333333033333333333333303333
>   333333333330333333333333333333333333333333313333333633333334
>   33330a333333333338333333363333333233333336333333333333333333
>   333337333333333333333033333336333333343333333633333333333333
>   3333330a3330306133303631333333333333333333333333333333303333
>   333333333331333333333333333033333336333333333333333333333333
>   333333360a33333336333333363333333533333333333333393333333633
>   333335333333363333333533333333333333363333333633333331333333
>   36333333310a333333363061333333333333333633333335333333333333
>   333133333333333333393333333633333333333333333333333733333333
>   3333333733330a3333333333353333333633333336333333363333333633
>   333333333333313333333333333331333333333333333233333333333333
>   323333333633330a33363333333330613333333833303631333333303336
>   333133333333333333343333333333333335333333333333333533333333
>   33333330333333330a333333383333333333333334333333363333333133
>   333333333333323333333333333332333333333333333333333336333333
>   3233333333333333310a3333333333333334306133333336333333313333
>   333333333334333333363333333333333333333333343333333633333334
>   333333363333333433330a33333333333233333333333333373333333333
>   333331333333363333333233333333333333313333333633333335333333
>   33333333393333333333330a333133333333333333373061333333333333
>   333033303631333333333333333733333333333333363333333333333339
>   3333333333333338333333330a3333333233333333333333303333333633
>   333335333333333333333233333336333333343333333333333332333333
>   333333333733333333333333310a33333333333333373333333330613333
>   333133333333333333373333333633333333333333333333333733333333
>   33333336333333333333333433330a333333333330333333333333333933
>   333336333333343333333633333331333333333333333733333336333333
>   3533333336333333353333333633330a3334333333363333333333333333
>   306133333333333333333333333633303631333333333333333933333330
>   333633313333333333333330333333330a33333334333333333333333633
>   333336333333363333333333333331333333333333333533333336333333
>   35333333363333333633333333333333360a333333333333333633333336
>   333333313061333333333333333633333333333333333333333333333332
>   3333333633333334333333363333333133330a3333333333303333333633
>   333336333333333333333433333336333333313333333333333333333333
>   363333333533333333333333393333333333330a33303333333333333330
>   333333363333333230613333333333333335333333333333333033303631
>   33333333333333303333333333333330333333330a333333303333333333
>   333330333333333333333033333333333333303333333033363331333036
>   3130610a

J-ji... how did you get *bold* in a GRUB menu?

Anyways, I'm bored, so I thought I'd use my <s>free labor</s> fellow community's knowledge to crack it.

And, Jim, **please don't send me stuff like this.**

Comment: Interesting fact: if you copy and paste the second clue it comes out in 2 columns.

Comment: Not 3: 1668620800a06564161616150a06170001640a8626706460a0061061010660a66596565661610a606165196770a56666112260a6061806106145500a8461226210a40616146464640a2716216590a17061006176980a20652642710a70611767640a0964617656560a460616061906100a466615656660a6610616264610a0664616590a006206150061000a00000610610610a

Comment: @Mithrandir Not quite it. Note that hex(`3#`) = ascii(`#`).

Comment: @Will I just ran it through a find and replace, with it just removing all of the threes...

Comment: @Mithrandir Yeah, and... why? To be frank, it's neither helpful nor particularly astute.

Comment: @Will people do it pretty often here for puzzles that have something like this. [example](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/31212/neurotic-frogs-ought-to-relax-in-mud-baths#comment93148_31212)

Answer (score 10):

If you

> convert the hex to ASCII four times, removing LF characters along the way

you get

> `1f8b0800ed1aaa5700031d8bc70dc03010c3fe9ee6aace19c775ff1122f8455084a223b14a4c4dd271b1e9170769820e2d271717c76409da7eedc369046f15ef66a632da0f4a3e900b50000000`

which as we can see from the beginning bytes is

> output from gzip (also clued by `G+0 R+8 U-12 B+14`: `G+0=G`, `R+8=Z`, `U-12=I`, `B+14=P` so that is G Z I P)

running it through

> `gunzip`

gives

> `48656c702120536f6d656f6e6520686173206c6f636b6564206d6520696e206120746f6d62210a`

which in ASCII is

> Help! Someone has locked me in a tomb![LF]

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE**: @Will already finished the first half of the question, but it was in a method different from the one I intended. So, I've posted this method here.

---

> The time is 5:55 A.M.

Quite a lot of **5**, right? Keep this in mind. **5** is very important.

> G+0 R+8 U-12 B+14 version 5.55

Once again the mysterious **5** shows up.

> The number-letter addition/subtraction can be parsed if we replace the  letters with their numerical positions in the alphabet (A = 1, B = 2, Z = 26, etc.)
>  Once parsed, it comes to `G Z I P`. This is another clue for later.

---

We then come to Jim's GRUB entry and the two clues.

HEADER-1T (5+1)

> `HEADER` is a reference to the decoded word, `GZIP` (a compression program).  `-1T` stands for `do this before you do the GZIP-related thing`. `<5+1>` is referring to the 5 iterations of hexadecimal encoding of Clue 2. The `+1` tells us there was a 6th iteration before the `GZIP-related thing`, which is compressing the data.

---

We then move on to Clue 2, which is

> the raw hexadecimal data.
> Piecing together the already derived information, and by simply looking at >!the data, we can infer we need to decode the data in 5 iterations, gunzip >!it, then decode the data in one final iteration.

The Unix command is this:

```
cat clue.txt | xxd -r -p - | xxd -r -p - | xxd -r -p - | xxd -r -p - | xxd -r -p - | gunzip -f | xxd -r -p -
```

which outputs the following text:

> Help! I'm locked in a tomb!

---

What's the meaning of the text? *I'll leave that for you to find out...*

Comment: Interestingly your final text *is different* from Will's!